# Codeigniter CRUD app: error updating a record (trying to get property of non-object)

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud

I have put together a CRUD application with Codeigniter 3. The update form has data validation set up, through the controller:

UPDATE *function*:

```
public function update($customer_id) {
        // data validation
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email address', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $data = [
            // insert into these database table fields
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email')
            ];
            $this->load->model('Customer');
            if ($this->Customer->updateCustomer($customer_id, $data)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('update-response','Customer successfully updated');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('update-response','Failed to update customer');
            }
            redirect('home');
        } else {
        $data = [       
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'id' => $customer_id
        ];
        $this->load->view('update', array("customer" => $data));
    }
}
```

It *does* go through the if, but *not* through the else.

UPDATE *form*:

```
<?php echo form_open("home/update/{$customer->id}"); ?>

    <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('first_name')) echo 'has-error';?>">
        <?php echo form_input('first_name', set_value('first_name', $customer->first_name),[
            'id' => 'first_name',
            'class' => 'form-control'
            ]);
        if(form_error('first_name')) echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
        echo form_error('first_name'); ?>                                     
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class = "btn btn-success btn-block"'); ?>
    </div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The UPDATE *model* is:

```
public function getAllCustomers($customer_id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('customers', array('id' => $customer_id));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row();
    }
}

public function updateCustomer($customer_id, $data) {
    return $this->db->where('id', $customer_id)->update('customers', $data);
}
```

The UPDATE **view**:

```
<?php echo form_open("home/update/{$customer->id}"); ?>
```

There is this problem with editing a record, inputting invalid data, then hitting the "Save button":

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: views/update.php
```

Such a problem appears *only on the update form*. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your else replace with this:

```
} else {
        $data = [       
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'id' => $customer_id
        ];
        $this->load->view('update', array("customer" => $data));
    }
```

Comment: The first error is gone, bit the second remains: `Message: Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass data to your view, so you are getting warning

```
$this->load->view('update');
```

To

```
$this->load->view('update', array('customer'=>$your_array));
```

It will be something like this

```
$this->load->view('update',array(
                 'customer'=>$this->Customer->updateCustomer($customer_id, $data)
              )
 );
```

Comment: The _Create_ part has no problem.  It is the _Update_ that throws errors.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir: basically you did not pass data to view, so you were getting undefined warning

Comment: If I update using valid data, all is well. The problem appears when I enter _invalid_ data (like _razvan_zamfir@yahoo_ for email) and hit the "Save" button. If I edit, enter razvan.zamfir@gmail.com for email, all is ok.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, because form validation fails `razvan_zamfir@yahoo` is not valid email

Answer (score 0):

Please Send the data in load view like..
e.g

```
$data['customer'] =  $this->Customer->updateCustomer($customer_id, $data);

$this->load->view('update',$data);
```

And then get data like `$customer->id` etc..

You can't pass data that's why the error was shown

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I have added more details to the issue.

Comment: From which method you get the data?

Comment: `$this->Customer->updateCustomer($customer_id, $data)` is the update method
$customers = $this->Customer->getCustomers($limit, $offset); lists all the customers, in chunks of 10

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass **$customer object** from your update function in controller. So your else part should look like-

```
$customer = $this->Customer->getCustomer($customer_id);
$this->load->view('update',$customer);
```

Comment: There is no `getCustomer($customer_id);` function.

Comment: Create one such function which gets the data of the customer.